# IE and facebook oath problem

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook javascript SDK for facebook login. It works for all browsers but IE. When a facebook popup opens asking to accept permissions, once you click Accept, it reloads that website in that popup window and no action is taken. I dont think FB events work:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
    login();
});
```

I tried to add channel html as documented in facebook page, but that didn't work neither... I also tried to ask just for 1 permission, but it still reloads that page.. So whats wrong with IE and how to make it work? again, all other browsers have no issues. This is broken for all IE versions..

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. All other browsers redirect correctly to facebook to complete the auth, but IE just keeps asking the orginal server over and over until the server hangs up.

I've captured the entire thing using tcpdump, here's a sample:

```
GET /fork HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: fbar.toolsteam.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=7f32d7e4acd63696bd8d0998913f608c; PHPSESSID=3260d25a1730179c9c09914e22e330d7

HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Mon, 07 May 2012 07:02:41 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=334f8739ecfdc934ce36186b9dea4b11; expires=Tue, 07-May-2013 07:02:41 GMT; path=/
Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=336243633108439&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffbar.toolsteam.com%2Ffork&state=3adc47d3453b34b4d50ad2d2651d9bd1&scope=publish_stream%2Coffline_access%2Cemail%2Cuser_groups%2Cpublish_actions
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
```

It just goes through this exact request and redirect until the browser gives up.

I'd sure like to find the solution.